# Serialize unpublished Polymer attributes

Tags: html, attributes, polymer

How can I get unpublished Polymer attributes to behave like published attributes?

unpublished obj attribute:

```
<dynamic-attributes obj="[object Object]"></dynamic-attributes>
```

published obj attribute:

```
<dynamic-attributes obj="{{ {'hello':'world'} }}"></dynamic-attributes>
```

Comment: could u post `dynamic-attributes` element code?

Comment: It won't help illustrate the question. You just need to know that `obj` is published in one, and not in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to grab the attributes before Polymer gets ahold of them. This can be done in the `created` lifecycle callback.

It can be used in conjunction with `injectBoundHTML` to render

```
<polymer-element>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        created: function () {
            var name = 'seriously-effect-' + this.type;

            // get mustache bindings before they get parsed and bound
            var instanceDecl = '<' + name + ' ';
            var attrs = this.attributes;
            for(var i = 0, l = attrs.length, attr; attr = attrs[i], i < l; ++i){
                instanceDecl += attr.name + '="' + attr.value + '" ';
            }
            instanceDecl += '></' + name + '>';

            //then parse attributes somehow... and stamp the template
            this.templateInstance.model.injectBoundHTML(instanceDecl, parsedAttributesModel);
        },

    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```